# GmailApp.getInboxThreads() skipping emails

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I seem to have a problem with GmailApp.getInboxThreads() in google apps script. When I import the emails from Gmail, it skips some emails seemingly at random. All emails at this Gmail account is forwarded from other accounts. Below is some sample code:

```
//This gets me the 5th email (correct)
var mail = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[4].getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();

//This gets me the 7th email (wrong)
var mail = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[5].getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential issue:**

According to the official documentation, [getInboxThreads()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreads):

> will fail when the size of all threads is too large for the system to
> handle. Where the thread size is unknown, and potentially very large,
> please use the 'paged' call, and specify ranges of the threads to
> retrieve in each call.

Therefore this might be the issue to your problem.

**Alternative solution:**

Instead, you can use [getInboxThreads(start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreadsstart,-max):

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);
//5th email
var mail = threads[4].getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();
//6th email
var mail = threads[5].getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();
```

Please keep in mind that this will give you **all the emails** regardless of their type (Primary, Social, Promotions).